# Como fazer uma regex para capturar uma sequência no números com pontos e strings

Tags: python, regex

Os exemplos são:

```
1.1. FLESH
1.1.2. BRAIN
```

Quero garantir que irei obter sequências **número.número. ... espaço e uma string em caixa alta** (não pode ser caixa baixa).

Tentei isto:

```
reg = r'[1-9][.]+\s\b[A-Z]*'
```

Porém, o resultado considera apenas a última sequência **número + ponto**:

Resultado:

```
2. BRAIN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o seguinte:

```
import re

texto = """
1.1. FLESH
1.1.2. BRAIN
"""

r = re.compile(r'^(?:[1-9]\.)+\s[A-Z]+', re.MULTILINE)
results = r.findall(texto)
print(results) # ['1.1. FLESH', '1.1.2. BRAIN']
```

Eu usei o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^`, que geralmente significa "início da string", mas com a *flag* [`MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE), ele passa a significar "início da linha". Isso vai garantir que só vai pegar os números se estiverem no início da linha (como parece ser o caso).

Depois tem a sequência `[1-9]\.` (um dígito de 1 a 9, seguido de um ponto). Tudo isso está entre parênteses, e o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` depois dos parênteses indica que todo esse grupo (dígito seguido de ponto) pode se repetir uma ou mais vezes. Assim, a regex pegará `1.`, `1.1.` e `1.1.1.1.1.`, etc.

Se quiser limitar a quantidade de vezes que o "dígito seguido de ponto" se repete, pode trocar o `+` por `{min,max}`. Por exemplo, `(?:[1-9]\.){2,5}` significa que só pode se repetir no mínimo 2 e no máximo 5 vezes (também é possível usar `{2,}`: no mínimo duas vezes, sem limite máximo).

Depois tem o espaço e `[A-Z]+` (uma ou mais letras maiúsculas). Na sua regex você usou `[A-Z]*` (zero ou mais letras), então sua regex vai dar *match* inclusive se não tiver nada depois do espaço. Se quiser forçar que tenha pelo menos uma letra, use o `+` (ou use as opções `{min,max}`, se quiser ser mais específico quanto à quantidade de letras permitidas).

Por fim, usei o método [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), que retorna uma lista com todas as ocorrências da regex que forem encontradas. O resultado é a lista:

```
['1.1. FLESH', '1.1.2. BRAIN']
```

Repare que nos parênteses foi usado `(?:`. Isso é para que eles sejam um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap). Se eu usasse somente `(`, eles seriam um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), e o método [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) retorna os grupos quando estes estão presentes. Como eu quero que retorne todo o *match*, eu precisei usar o grupo de não-captura.

---

Se você está buscando uma string por vez, não precisa da *flag* `MULTILINE`:

```
r = re.compile(r'^(?:[1-9]\.)+\s[A-Z]+')
print(r.findall('1.1. FLESH')) # ['1.1. FLESH']
print(r.findall('1.1.2. BRAIN')) # ['1.1.2. BRAIN']
```

No caso, `findall` é útil para encontrar todas as ocorrências de uma vez (caso tenha mais de uma na string). Mas se você só quiser uma ocorrência, pode usar o método [`match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match):

```
r = re.compile(r'^(?:[1-9]\.)+\s[A-Z]+')
match = r.match('1.1. FLESH')
if match: # se encontrou um match
    print(match.group()) # 1.1. FLESH
```

---

Se os números não ocorrem necessariamente no início da linha, basta remover o `^` da regex (e também não precisa da *flag* `MULTILINE`):

```
r = re.compile(r'(?:[1-9]\.)+\s[A-Z]+')
```

Assim, o texto poderia ser `1.1. FLESH  1.1.2. BRAIN` (tudo na mesma linha), que o `findall` encontrará ambas as ocorrências (como não ficou claro que os números só ocorrem no início da linha, escolha a opção que se encaixar melhor nos seus casos).

O método `findall` retorna uma lista com as ocorrências encontradas. Mas se quiser iterar por elas, basta usar o método [`finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer), que retorna um iterador de [*matches*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects). A diferença é que `findall` retorna uma lista de strings, enquanto `finditer` retorna objetos [*match*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects), que contém várias informações sobre o trecho encontrado. Ex:

```
import re

texto = "1.1. FLESH  1.1.2. BRAIN"

r = re.compile(r'(?:[1-9]\.)+\s[A-Z]+')

for m in r.finditer(texto):
    print('String "{}" encontrada entre as posições {} e {}'.format(m.group(), m.start(), m.end()))
```

Saída:

```
String "1.1. FLESH" encontrada entre as posições 1 e 11
String "1.1.2. BRAIN" encontrada entre as posições 13 e 25
```

---

Na sua regex você usou `[1-9][.]+` (um dígito de 1 a 9, seguido de um ou mais pontos), por isso ele não pega todos os dígitos.

Além disso, o atalho `\b` ([*word boundary* - "fronteira de palavra"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)) é redundante, pois como a regex já indica que deve ter um espaço antes das letras, isso já denota uma fronteira de palavra (uma posição da string que possui um caractere alfanumérico antes e um não-alfanumérico depois, ou vice-versa). Por isso o `\b` não é necessário neste caso.

Comment: OK, @hkotsubo. Irei testar e te darei um feedback.

Answer (score 0):

### Expressão Regular

Caso a string esteja na mesma linha, e não possua uma nova linha (CR ou LF), utilizar a seguinte Expressão Regular:

`\d+(?:\.\d+)*[\s\S]*?\D(?=\s*(?:\d|$))`

E ver a [demo no Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UrLVzV/2):

[image: Resultado da Regex 101]

**Detalhes**

- `\d+` - 1 ou mais dígitos
- `(?:\.\d+)*` - zero ou mais sequências de:

  - `\.` - ponto
  - `\d+` - 1 ou mais dígitos
  - `*` - Quantificadorganancioso
- `[\s\S]*?` - qualquer 0+ chars, mínimo possível, até o primeiro...
- `\D` combina qualquer símbolo não-dígito
- O `(?=\s*(?:\d+|$))` verificador positivo exige a presença de zero ou mais espaços em branco `[ \r\n\t\f\v]` (`(\s*)`) seguidos de um ou mais dígitos `(\d+)` ou fim de string `($)` imediatamente à direita.

### Python

Para o programa no Python, utilize a biblioteca [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)